# Urls no responden - Django

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, django-urls

Tengo un problema con mis `urls` en `Django`, aquí mi `urls.py`:

```
from .views import (
    CouponListView, CouponDetailView, buy_coupon, UserCouponListView, CouponOfResaleCreateView,
    CouponOfResaleListView,
) 

from django.urls import path, include

coupons_patterns = ([
    path('', CouponListView.as_view(), name = 'list'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', UserCouponListView.as_view(), name = 'user'),
    path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
    path('coupon/<int:pk>/buy-<slug:slug>/', buy_coupon, name = 'buy-coupon'),

    path('resale/', include([
        path('', CouponOfResaleListView.as_view(), name = 'resale_list'),
        path('create/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponOfResaleCreateView.as_view(), name = 'create'),
    ])),

], 'coupons')
```

Las `urls` que no funcionan o que no responden son estas:

```
path('resale/', include([
        path('', CouponOfResaleListView.as_view(), name = 'resale_list'),
        path('create/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponOfResaleCreateView.as_view(), name = 'create'),
])),
```

No me sale error solo no responden, es decir, si yo quiero acceder a una de las `urls` que mostré anteriormente, por ejemplo a la `resale_list` en ves de mostrarme lo que debería mostrarme, me muestra el resultado de acceder a la `url` `user`.

En la `url` del navegador esta la `url` correctamente pero me muestra el HTML de otra `url`, que en este caso es la `url` `user`.

La forma de solucionarlo es mover esa porción de `urls` arriba, de la siguiente manera:

```
coupons_patterns = ([
    path('resale/', include([
        path('', CouponOfResaleListView.as_view(), name = 'resale_list'),
        path('create/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponOfResaleCreateView.as_view(), name = 'create'),
    ])),

    path('', CouponListView.as_view(), name = 'list'),
    path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
    path('coupon/<int:pk>/buy-<slug:slug>/', buy_coupon, name = 'buy-coupon'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', UserCouponListView.as_view(), name = 'user'),

], 'coupons')
```

Otra solución es mover la `url` `user` abajo de dicha porción de `urls`, de la siguiente manera:

```
coupons_patterns = ([
    path('', CouponListView.as_view(), name = 'list'),
    path('<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponDetailView.as_view(), name = 'detail'),
    path('coupon/<int:pk>/buy-<slug:slug>/', buy_coupon, name = 'buy-coupon'),

    path('resale/', include([
        path('', CouponOfResaleListView.as_view(), name = 'resale_list'),
        path('create/<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/', CouponOfResaleCreateView.as_view(), name = 'create'),
    ])),

    path('<slug:slug>/', UserCouponListView.as_view(), name = 'user'),

], 'coupons')
```

Pero ¿Por que pasa esto?, ¿Porque dependiendo el orden de las `urls` hace que suceda dicho problema?.

¿Alguna solución?, ya que no me gusta tener mis `urls` en ese orden para que funcionen.

Comment: Saludos como estas llamando a las URLS actualmente podrias agregar tu html ? adicional tienes "'resale/'," dedusco que es o intentas llamar a  urls.py de tu app "resale"...?

Comment: En realidad no tengo una app `resale`. Y que HTML agrego?

Comment: Como? No te entiendo.

Comment: como estas llamando a tus urls desde tu template es decir algo asi "{% url 'miapp:mi_url' %}"...o "/mi/url"

Comment: OK, las llamo así: `coupons:resale_list`

Comment: Así específicamente: `{% url 'coupons:resale_list' %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El motivo por el que te ocurre esto es muy sencillo, cada una de las urls es un `regex`. Django comprueba una por una si la url introducida coincide con las urls que has indicado en `urls.py`. En el momento que encuentra una coincidencia, la utiliza. Por ese motivo te funciona al reordenar las urls. Te recomendaría utilizar urls más específicas.

- `/recurso1/id/id`
- `/recurso2/id/id`

Comment: Entonces confundia `'coupons/slug'` con `'coupons/resale'`, y creia que el `'resale'` era el `slug`, llamando asi a la vista, verdad?

Comment: Lo acabo de comprobar en la vista, imprimiendo `self.kwargs` y exactamente eso esta sucediendo, gracias por tu respuesta! saludos!